# How to plot training data and training target for SVC

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

I'm trying to visualize my data, by plotting it, after loading images and extracting its keypoints. However, when i try to scatter it, before plotting, i get the error my x and y values should be the same size.

This is what i get from loading my own dataset:

Data:

```
[[0.06887255 0.06887255 0.06887255 ... 0.08921569 0.08921569 0.08921569]
 [0.06666667 0.06666667 0.06666667 ... 0.08823529 0.08823529 0.08823529]
 [0.07598039 0.07598039 0.07598039 ... 0.08848039 0.08848039 0.08848039]
 ...
 [0.01568627 0.01568627 0.01568627 ... 0.1129902  0.1129902  0.1129902 ]
 [0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 ... 0.1129902  0.1129902  0.1129902 ]
 [0.01666667 0.01666667 0.01666667 ... 0.1129902  0.1129902  0.1129902 ]]
```

target: `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4]`

Code for reproduction

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import numpy as np
 import skimage
 import cv2
 from skimage.io import imread
 from skimage.transform import resize

DATADIR = "C:/Dataset"
CATEGORIES = ["class 1", "class 2", "class 3", "class 4", "class 5"]
def load_image_files(fullpath, dimension=(35, 35)):
    descr = "A image classification dataset"
    flat_data = []
    target = []
    images = []
    dimension=(64, 64)
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        for person in os.listdir(path):
            personfolder = os.path.join(path, person)
            for imgname in os.listdir(personfolder):
                class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
                fullpath = os.path.join(personfolder, imgname)
                imageList = skimage.io.imread(fullpath)
                orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=1)
                orb = cv2.ORB_create()
                key_points = [cv2.KeyPoint(65, 9, 10), cv2.KeyPoint(66, 40, 10),cv2.KeyPoint(49, 200, 10), cv2.KeyPoint(76, 187, 10), cv2.KeyPoint(139, 188, 10), cv2.KeyPoint(176, 200, 10)]
                kp, des = orb.compute(imageList, key_points)
                kparray = cv2.drawKeypoints(imageList, kp, None, flags=cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
                img_resized = resize(kparray, dimension, anti_aliasing=True, mode='reflect')
                img_resized = img_resized.flatten()

                flat_data.append(img_resized)
                images.append(flat_data)
                target.append(class_num)

    flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
    target = np.array(target)
    images = np.array(images)
    return Bunch(data=flat_data,
                     target=target,
                     target_names=CATEGORIES,
                     images=images,
                     DESCR=descr)
```

Its worth noting that inside each class, there is a folder for John Doe, basically it goes Class 1/John Doe, Class 2/John Doe, Class 3/John Doe, Class 4/John Doe, Class 5/John Doe, with whatever image in each.

Im loading the images like this: `image_dataset = load_image_files("C:\Dataset")`

Then i tried simply scattering and plotting:

```
plt.scatter(image_dataset.data, image_dataset.target)
plt.show()
```

Got the error saying that x and y should be the same size.

I would like to know how can i resize my data (x value) to my classes value ( y value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here plt.scatter() needs an X and a Y value for each dot it is going draw in XY 2D plane. Each dot represents a sample from your dataset. So plt.scatter() takes 1D arrays or lists for X and Y values.

```
EX: 
X = [1,2,3,4] , Y = [4,2,1,4]
Dot1 => 1,4
Dot2 => 2,2
.
.
.
```

Here your image_dataset.data is actually lists of flattened image pixel values. It is a 2D data and it does not make any sense using it to plot a scatter graph. Plus you are trying to pass that as X-axis coordinates. I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with that.

If you are trying to plot the images and state their classes you should try to draw subplots with plt.plot(..). You can find the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html).

EDIT #1:
You could try:

```
image_dataset.target = [label for label in image_dataset.target
            for i in range(image_dataset.data.shape[0])]
image_dataset.data = image_dataset.data.flatten()
```

Here we first flatten the image.data from 2D to 1D. Then we create labels as the length of pixel data dictates. So we label each pixel from 1st image as 1.

Here is a minimal example:

```
X = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
Y = np.array([1,1,2,2])

Y = [label for label in Y
            for i in range(X.shape[1])]
X = X.flatten()

len(X)
>>12
len(Y)
>>12
```

Comment: Just one question though, why flatten again the data? Im doing that inside the function, im confused in that part. My function basically returns the categories, which should be labels that are the targets, and the data, for clarification, im extracting features from the keypoints and using it for classification. I tried running your code it gives me: "IndexError: tuple index out of range". Its important to note what my code does: it sets 22 points on an image, extracts their features to a 22 dimensional vector, where i want to load them for classification.

Comment: Alright I might have jumped to conclusion here with your code because of the names of the variables. Could you tell me what exactly is image_dataset.data and its shape? I assumed image_dataset.data is a 2D array consisting of multiple 1D arrays.

Comment: Absolutely, no problem. So, basically i get a dictionary with arrays in it, which is returned by Bunch(data=flat_data,
                     target=target,
                     target_names=CATEGORIES,
                     images=images,
                     DESCR=descr). The actual shape of img_resized or image.append is (12288,). Given that img_resized is inside the dictionary.  Now, >> the actual image_dataset.data.shape is (25, 12288)

Comment: If image_dataset.data.shape is (25, 12288) you cannot pass it as a X-axis variable for plt.scatter().  image_dataset.data needs to be 1D before you can use it to draw a scatter plot. I made a change with my code could you try it again please?

Comment: Following your code it gives now: ValueError: x and y must be the same size

Comment: Oh shoot crucial mistake. Check it out now. Big sorry about it. The order of the lines are wrong. :P

Comment: Well, image_dataset.data.shape is  (307200,) and image_dataset.target.shape actually gives an error when i print its shape: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'. EDIT: even changing the order of the lines, getting printed the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214500/discussion-between-meto-and-john-jones).